# Can I use libraries for my Ubuntu Touch app?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, libraries

I have created an Ubuntu Touch app that uses .a libraries that I have written myself. Can I use those in Ubuntu Touch? If yes, where do I store them and how can I access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include them with your app, installing them to the same directory as the rest of your files.  If the rest of your app is in QML, and you are using qmlscene to launch it, use the -I flag to add your library's path to where qmlscene will try to load them from.